# How to connect different classes together?

Tags: python, function, class, attributes

I want to make a program that makes information about music albums: title, artists and songs in the album. About the artist, name or names(if it is more than one artist) should be registered. For the songs, song title, and if you want, the name of the composer should be registered. 
The program should have classes for Albums, Artists and Songs. The class for the artist is having a function that return "true" if the artist is a solo artist, "false" if not. Every Album is having a serial number from 1 and up, in the order they were added in the system. The class for Album is having function  that returns the serial number.

At the end, the program should have a function that goes through the album list, and print the album title and the song titles for a named artist. If there is no artists given, the whole list is being printed.

I have tried a bit, but i dont understand how to classes is connected, and how you can make a list that will save all the data.

```
class Artists:


    def __init__(self, artist_name):
        self.artist_name = artist_name


        artist_list = {}
        artist_list.append(artist_name)

        if range(artist_list)==1: print("True")
        else: print("False")


class Album:
    totalAlbums=0 #for automatically generate serial numbers
    serialnumber = None

    def __init__(self, albumtitle, artist, serialnumber):
        Album.totalAlbums=Album.totalAlbums+1
        self.serienummer=Album.totalAlbums
        self.albumtitle=albumtitle
        self.artist=artist
        self.serialnumber=serialnumber

        self.songs = {}

        artist.add_song(self)


class Song:

        def __init__(self, songtitle, composer):
            self.songtitle=sangtitle
            self.composer=composer

for artist in albumlist: print()
```

Comment: Your question is too broad for SO's Q&A format. You should restrict it to something  narrower and better defined if you want to receive an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You are in the 'requirements' phase of the project you are working on.

---

You can psuedo-code your ideas at this point, but as the other comments suggest, actual code still needs more requirements.

---

I would suggest examining your assumptions at this point and understand a data integrity many to many relationships in your data.

---

IE

---

An album can have many composers, as a song could too.
In your writing you seem to assume each song has 1 and only 1 composer.

---

high level definition of requirement

---

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Requirement

---

software definition of requirement

---

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_requirements_specification